# Detect redirect and display website accordingly

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

I have a main website that redirects to the mobile site when necessary. The mobile site looks completely different and is stored in the sub-directory. When mobile users choose to view main(full) website, I'd like to:

1. redirect to the full site
2. have the full site detect the redirect (so it will display as the full site)
3. be able to toggle back to mobile version if desired.

What is the most efficient way to accomplish all of this?

This is how I redirect to the mobile version from the main:

```
if (screen.width < 1280) {
    window.location = "http://mainSite.com/mobile/home.html";
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: just add a flag in `url` which is like `?disable=1` and just put `and` condition with above code before that check in url for that flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple ways you can do this:

1) You can pass a query parameter in the URL letting the consuming page know your intent.

```
//m=0 means MobileVersion=No
window.location = "http://mainSite.com/home.html?m=0";
```

Pros: Easy to do

Cons: If every page performs this check, you have to continue passing this parameter on every page. Yahoo does this on their homepage, but when I click a subpage, I get the mobile version again cause they didn't continue passing the URL param.

2) Use a cookie to store the user's site version preference. Then check it again in code.

Setting cookie:

```
document.cookie = 'prefmobile=0; expires=Thu, 1 Apr 2015 23:59:59 UTC; path=/'
```

PROS: Persist across page calls, without messing with URL params.

CONS: If user's cookies are disabled...

Then there's always Responsive design that forces mobile no matter if you want it or not. ;)

OR just have a button where users can switch to different versions if they want to. Maybe show a non-intrusive message div at the top that says "Mobile version available--click here!" if the screenwidth < 1280.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! I don't think too many people disable cookies in the mobile world but I'm going to play around with both solutions.